# Store huge number of records with single SaveContext call

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Is there any maximum size / number of records that can be added to database table with EntityFramework without problems with using a single `context.SaveChanges()` after?

Imagine that we have an entity:

```
public class DbEntity
{
    public int DbEntityId {get;set;}
    public decimal Value {get; set;}
    public string Text {get; set;}
}
```

And now we would like to add a huge collection of `DbEntity` items into database table, like:

```
var collection = new DbEntity[99999]; // data initialization ommited
context.DbEntities.AddRange(collection);
```

And then single call:

```
context.SaveChanges();
```

Should it be fine, or we should split the data that is about to be added into db and handle it in as a chunks ->

```
context.DbEntities.AddRange(collection.Take(1000));
context.SaveChanges();
context.DbEntities.AddRange(collection.Skip(1000).Take(1000));
context.SaveChanges();
```

etc?

Comment: EF shouldn't have problems with huge injections. The only reason to split it into chunks is to locate possible errors more easy and the performance.

Comment: this is possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940225/fastest-way-of-inserting-in-entity-framework Maybe it can help you.